# CakePHP count all items with ID within a certain parrent

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a database table with id, template_id and destination_id. And I want to count the number of template_id's within every destination_id. So I get an array with totals per template within a destination.

In the model I have put this:

```
var $virtualFields = array(
    'template_count' => 'COUNT(Content.template_id)'
);
```

And I do get the counts per template. Only I am clueless how to get the total count

Comment: Have you tried a standard find() with conditions?

Comment: Yes I did, but then I would have to do a query per destination in combination with a template_id. That works, but in our user story it would mean 15*150 queries. I heard there is an option to get an array per destination with count values per template

Answer (score 1):

I would *not* define a virtual field in the model based on an aggregate function.

I think what you need is a query that looks like:

```
SELECT Content.destination_id, COUNT(Content.template_id) AS template_count
FROM contents AS CONTENT
GROUP BY Content.destination_id
```

Try using this Cakephp code:

```
$this->find('all' array(
  'fields' => array('Content.destination_id'
                  , 'COUNT(Content.template_id) AS template_count'),
  'group' => array('Content.destination_id')));
```

Comment: I would use a virtual field. It is cleaner in 2.x.

Comment: This also gives me the totals per destination id, while I need to have per destination_id the count for template 1, template 2 etc

Comment: @mark - Have you used aggregate functions in a virtual field? MySQL will only return 1 row when the `SELECT` has an aggregate function and there is not a `GROUP BY`. Does 2.x somehow take care of this problem?

Comment: @AlvinBakker - Please put sample data in your question along with the result set you are trying to get.

Comment: Well, a COUNT would have to be `COUNT(*)`, of course. Otherwise the query would need to be written differently, anyway, for the reasons you mentioned above. But anything you write with normal sql, you can also write with virtual fields. That was my point.